# How to change property values of an already existing css class in Angular2+ controller?

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a css class '.users' in my syles.css file and this class has a propery of color. Now I want to change the color propery value of users class base on some condition in my controller (for example in ngOnInt()) dynamically? please consider that I do not want to do anything in template, so only typescript solutions are accepted!

Comment: can you explain the use case a little more ?

Comment: You can add another class that overrides the color property. Why won't that work? You can also tweak the style attribute of the native element if that's something you want to do. Rewriting the rule inside a css class is not something that you can do at runtime.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a good approach to handle the styling this way. We need more declarative approach rather than coding imperatively.

Just for the sake of doing this approach which I highly un-recommend:

In **styles.css**:

```
--users-text-color: black;

.users {
  color: var(--users-text-color: black);
}
```

And in **component.ts**

```
constructor(private rendrer: Renderer2, private document: Document) {}

onInit(): void {
  this.renderer.setProperty(this.document, '--users-text-color', 'white');
}
```

**THE PROPER WAY:**
The proper way would be to override styles like this

In **styles.css**:

```
.users {
  color: black;
}
```

And in **component.scss**

```
// Component level over-ride
.users {
   color: white;
}
```